# How to access a property in kv from python script in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Following is the main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import (ScreenManager, Screen)
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import *

class EmotionsScreen(Screen):
    def button_press(self, emotion_str):
        print (self.ids[emotion_str].emotion)

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

class HappyButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    def on_press(self):
        print(self.emotion)

class SadButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    def on_press(self):
        print(self.emotion)

class TiredButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    def on_press(self):
        print(self.emotion)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManagement()
        sm.current = 'Emotions'
        return sm

if __name__=='__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Following is the contents of myapp.kv file:
    :
        EmotionsScreen:

```
<EmotionsScreen>:
    name:'Emotions'

    HappyButton:
        id: happy
        source: "happy.png"
        pos: (-200, 100)
        emotion: "Happy"
    SadButton:
        id: sad
        source: "sad.png"
        pos: (0, 100)
        emotion: "Sad"
    TiredButton:
        id: tired
        source: "tired.png"
        pos: (200, 100)
        emotion: "Tired"
```

Upon running the application, and clicking on the three buttons, I am getting the following behavior:

- Clicking the happy button prints "Sad" :)
- Clicking the sad button prints "Tired"
- Clicking the tired button prints "Tired"

The above happens even if I call a single callback (inside app, with arguments supplied), as follows:

main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import (ScreenManager, Screen)
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import *

class EmotionsScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManagement()
        sm.current = 'Emotions'
        return sm

    def button_press(self, *args):
        print (args)


if __name__=='__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

myapp.kv:

```
<ScreenManagement>:
    EmotionsScreen:

<EmotionsScreen>:
    name:'Emotions'

    ImageButton:
        source: "happy.png"
        pos: (-200, 100)
        on_press: app.button_press("Happy")
    ImageButton:
        source: "sad.png"
        pos: (0, 100)
        on_press: app.button_press("Sad")
    ImageButton:
        source: "tired.png"
        pos: (200, 100)
        on_press: app.button_press("Tired")
```

I expect it to print, "Happy", "Sad" and "Tired" upon clicking the three buttons respectively. May I know where I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These images seem to be placed randomly. Example using buttons as mockups:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import (ScreenManager, Screen)
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import *
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<EmotionsScreen>:
    name:'Emotions'
    HappyButton:
        id: happy
        pos: (-200, 100)
        text: "Happy"
        emotion: "Happy"
    SadButton:
        id: sad
        pos: (0, 100)
        text: "Sad"
        emotion: "Sad"
    TiredButton:
        id: tired
        pos: (200, 100)
        text: "Tired"
        emotion: "Tired"
''')

class EmotionsScreen(Screen):
    def button_press(self, emotion_str):
        print (self.ids[emotion_str].emotion)

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

class HappyButton(Button):
    def on_press(self):
        print(self.emotion)

class SadButton(Button):
    def on_press(self):
        print(self.emotion)

class TiredButton(Button):
    def on_press(self):
        print(self.emotion)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManagement()
        sm.add_widget(EmotionsScreen())
        sm.current = 'Emotions'
        return sm

if __name__=='__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

You should rather put a layout inside your screen to manage its widgets:

```
Builder.load_string('''
<EmotionsScreen>:
    name:'Emotions'

    BoxLayout:
        HappyButton:
            id: happy
            text: "Happy"
            emotion: "Happy"
        SadButton:
            id: sad
            text: "Sad"
            emotion: "Sad"
        TiredButton:
            id: tired
            text: "Tired"
            emotion: "Tired"
''')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked! I have less than 15 points, so I could not vote your answer up